# IOS Table View:Table View Custom Cell While Scrolling It pre-populates the Value in another cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**to Create Cell:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    AddEventsCell *cell= 
      [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"addevents"];
    NSLog(@"cell %@",cell);
    if(cell==nil){
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"addevents" 
                                              bundle:nil] 
        forCellReuseIdentifier:@"addevents"];
        cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"addevents"];


    }
     cell.tag=indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}
```

**Display Cell**:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  willDisplayCell:(AddEventsCell *)cell 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"index path %d == %d",indexPath.row,cell.tag);
    if(cell.tag==0){

        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Event Name";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"0";
        [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];

    }else if(cell.tag==1){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Category";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"1";
         [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];
    }else if(cell.tag==2){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Upload Image";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"2";
          [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];

    }else if(cell.tag==3){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Time";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"3";
          [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];

    }else if(cell.tag==4){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Location";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"4";
          [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];

    }else if(cell.tag==5){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Description";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"5";
          [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];

    }else if(cell.tag==6){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Factilitator";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"6";
          [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];

    }else if(cell.tag==7){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Price";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"7";
          [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];

    }else if(cell.tag==8){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Notes";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"8";
          [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];

    }else if(cell.tag==9){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Duration";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"9";
          [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];

    }else if(cell.tag==10){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Program";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"10";
          [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];

    }else if(cell.tag==11){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"pre-requiment";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"11";
          [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];

    }else if(cell.tag==12){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Target";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"12";
          [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];

    }else if(cell.tag==13){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Contact";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"13";
          [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];

    }else if(cell.tag==14){
        cell.lableFiledValue.text=@"Website";
        cell.textFieldValue.placeholder=@"14";
          [self.textfieldArray addObject:cell.textFieldValue];
    }


}
```

all cell object are added in `self.textfieldArray`

**If I enter the values in 1st box, means it will display same value in 7th box.**

to stop pre-populating of data.

Comment: You can create a `NSArray` for `labelFieldValue` and can use in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as **cell.lableFiledValue.text=[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];**

Answer (score 2):

In `AddEventsCell` implement `prepareForReuse`:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
    self.lableFiledValue.text = nil;
    self.textFieldValue.placeholder = nil;
}
```

Another thing - `willDisplayCell` calls every time the tableView is about to display the cell - which means multiple times for the same cell when the user scrolls the tableView back and forth. You might want to find another way to add bojects to `textfieldArray`. You can do that using `NSMutableArray` and `setObject:atIndexedSubscript:`, or by checking if given object is already exist in the array before adding it.

Comment: if i enter this code when i enter some values in textfiled after i scroll the entered value is disappread.

Comment: As it should - Every time you scroll a cell out of the screen it's being used to show another cell of a different index. You have to re-draw all the cell information that is index-specific, including anything that has changed in the cell. You can save the text form the textField into an array using `UITextFieldDelegate` methods, and  than re-put the text from the array in `willDisplayCell`. Read more: [AppleDocs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:).